# How to read content of text file using function

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates

I am new to Python.
Following this example: 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f

I have a message template file message.txt that uses template string `“${PERSON_NAME}”` . The string will be replaced with actual name of the person.

[image]

So I am using this function but something is not going right, because it gives me weird output"

```
from string import Template

def read_template(filename):
    with open(r'C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\SQL_NeedToKnow\Python\message.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        template_file_content = template_file.read(100)
    return Template(template_file_content)
print(read_template(r'C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\SQL_NeedToKnow\Python\message.txt'))
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using the `string.Template` class? Why do you think the ouput is "weird"? What did you expect, given that you wrote a function that explicitly returns a `Template` object?

Comment: If you just want to read the file, you don't *need* to use `string.Template`, just return `template_file.read(100)`. Unless, of course, you do, in which case this is the expected behavior. You're calling the instance's `__str__` method by `print`ing it.

Comment: Reading template file is just a piece of my project. I just want to make sure the function works properly so I can continue.

Comment: @ekhumoro, so output `<string.Template object at 0x000000789AA19080>` is correct?  Sorry, like I said, I dont know much about python...yet.

Comment: @Oleg. Of course it is. Please answer all the questions in my previous comment.

Comment: Please avoid *"I am new to ..."*, because it doesn't help anyone to answer your question. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) on Meta StackExchange.

Comment: Also: [Never post text content as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readlines()` function to read the file.

```
def read_from_file():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
         content = file.readlines()
     print content
```

This will print the entire content of the file.

Also `readline()` function will read a single line from file whereas `readlines()` will read the entire content of the file